# Выборка из трех таблиц PL/SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Таблицы в бд

**Customers:**

```
cust_id number(10)|cust_name varchar2(50)|email varchar2(50)|order_sum varchar2(50)|id_firms number(10)
```

**Firms:**

```
f_name varchar2(50)|f_id number(10)|itme_cooperation timestamp|email varchar2(50)
```

**Orders:**

```
order_id number(10)|order_sum number(10)|oder_date timestamp|customers_id number(10)
```

Мне необходимо выбрать заказчиков с суммой их заказов и имена фирм для которых делалось наибольшее количество заказов.Получить это можно только через customers.id_firms , насколько я понимаю.

Вот так я вывожу имена заказчиков (customers) и суммы их заказов

```
select customers.CUST_NAME, sum(orders.order_sum) sum_of_orders
from  customers, orders
group by customers.CUST_NAME,customers.CUST_ID, orders.customers_id
having customers.CUST_ID = orders.CUSTOMERS_ID
ORDER BY customers.CUST_NAME;
```

Но как сюда добавить еще и выборку максимального количества связей customers - firms, что бы показать для каких фирм у этого заказчика наибольшее количество заказов?

**Результатом должно быть:**

```
Имена фирм | Имена заказчиков | Сумма заказов (общая для заказчика, а не для конкретной фирмы в первом столбце)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит писать условия соединения в предложении HAVING.
Oracle конечно умный и всё поймёт(выполнит проверку условий до групировки), но HAVING совершенно не для этого сделан.
Как минимум в WHERE, я же перенёс в JOIN.

Во вторых на фирму у вас ссылается заказчик. Т.е. у одного заказчика всега ОДНА фирма, а значит выбираем "любую" в группе функцией MAX.

```
select customers.CUST_NAME, MAX(firms.f_name)f_name, sum(orders.order_sum) sum_of_orders
from  customers
  INNER JOIN orders ON customers.CUST_ID = orders.CUSTOMERS_ID
  INNER JOIN firms ON firms.f_id = customers.id_firms
group by customers.CUST_NAME,customers.CUST_ID
ORDER BY customers.CUST_NAME;
```

Вы точно правильно указали схему?
По логике на фирму должна ссылаться таблица Orders. и тогда задача решается уже интересней. С дополнительной промежутосной группировкой.

```
select CUST_NAME, SUM(sum_of_orders)sum_of_orders, 
  --выбираем имя фирмы с максимальным количеством заказов
  MAX(CASE WHEN cnt_firm=cnt_max THEN f_name END)f_name_max_cnt
from(
  select customers.CUST_NAME, customers.CUST_ID, firms.f_name, 
    sum(orders.order_sum) sum_of_orders,
    --подсчитываем количество заказов для каждой фирмы, и максимальное количество
    count(*)as cnt_firm, max(count(*))over(partition by customers.CUST_ID)cnt_max
  from  customers
    INNER JOIN orders ON customers.CUST_ID = orders.CUSTOMERS_ID
    INNER JOIN firms ON firms.f_id = orders.id_firms
  group by customers.CUST_NAME, customers.CUST_ID, firms.f_id, firms.f_name
)T
group by CUST_NAME, CUST_ID
```

Если у нескольких фирм максимальное количество, данный запрос найдёт только одну из них.
Можно их конечно перечислить через запятую, но не вижу в этом бизнес смысла.
Хотя если надо, могу дополнить.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Добавил в Orders ссылку на фирму, но Oracle SQL Developer ругается на запрос с промежуточной группировкой:  
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 124 Column: 59

Comment: @TehD, там опечатка. CASW вместо CASE. Поправил.

Comment: ...действительно) я и не заметил, хотя в упор смотрел. ))) Спасибо!